# Postgres - Insert into table is stuck

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-14

I have a dynamic query that creates a table and then inserts data into this table (in Postgres 14.2). It works OK in 99% of cases, but sometimes insert just gets stuck.

SELECT part is not a problem (when I run select separately it finishes within a minute, it's ~500k lines, ~130 MB of data). And I found out when I run SELECT INTO table FROM ... it works OK, too (but again, I'm not sure that it's OK in 100% of cases).

But INSERT INTO table (columns) SELECT ... sometimes doesn't work.

It doesn't matter if I run the query directly or
cmd := 'create table; insert'; and execute cmd;

Unfortunately, I don't have admin rights and I don't have access to the database server OS...

Do you have any idea what could be wrong? I asked for help from our dba, but I would like to know and understand myself (and I also expect they will ask questions).

Comment: This is too vague. When it "gets stuck", do you see `wait_event_type` and `wait_event` in `pg_stat_activity`? What are the exact SQL statements, in what order are they executed and where are the transaction boundaries? Are additional statements running in parallel?

Comment: Unfortunately, both are NULL, there isn't any wait visible. There also isn't any blocking process. No, there isn't any other process. I have killed all other sessions during testing.

Comment: SQL Statement doesn't contain anything strange.
It is just:
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_name;

CREATE TABLE table_name (
columns
);

INSERT INTO table_name(columns)
Select ...;

Comment: If there is no other session, and a statement doesn't finish, it either has a lot to do, or data corruption or a bug sent PostgreSQL into an endless loop. In that case, [generate a stack trace](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Generating_a_stack_trace_of_a_PostgreSQL_backend) from the running backend. That would help find out what PostgreSQL is doing.

Comment: ok, thank you, I'll wait for dba answer and ask them for the stack trace and post an update here.

Comment: Please edit your question to add more details, instead of replying in the comments section.  And, Schema and the sqls used might help.